# CD with AWS ElasticBeanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Since the correct practice appears to be `.ebextensions` being added to the gitignore, what's the best way to handle CD when using EB as your platform? I can't just configure my pipelines to run `eb deploy` on a successful build, since the build box will have no idea of any configuration relating to the stack in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve it by doing below  -

- Don't ignore `.ebextensions`, you will need it for CD & it's good to
  keep it versioned. (People add it to `.gitignore` so that it doesn't
  conflict across developers while collaborating since Beanstalk
  started with Developer centric environment)
- Put configs into `.ebextension` which are static & doesn't change across the environments like your cloudwatch(Disk, Memory etc) &
  autoscaling stuffs.
- Dynamic pieces(`.elasticbeanstalk`) should be included while doing the deployment like application, environment name etc. You can
  use shell as build step in CD & change the configs as per your job. I
  do it something as below -

> Continuous Deployment build shell script

```
mkdir -p .elasticbeanstalk

cat > .elasticbeanstalk/config.yml << EOF
branch-defaults:
  default:
    environment: dev-api
environment-defaults:
  dev-api:
    branch: null
    repository: null
global:
  application_name: v2
  default_ec2_keyname: DEV
  default_platform: arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:ap-southeast-1::platform/Multi-container
    Docker running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.7.5
  default_region: ap-southeast-1
  include_git_submodules: true
  instance_profile: null
  platform_name: null
  platform_version: null
  profile: null
  sc: git
  workspace_type: Application
EOF
```

- You can deploy it now to Beanstalk by using `--staged`

  ```
  eb deploy $APP_ENVIRONMENT -l ${BUILD_TAG}_${GIT_COMMIT} --timeout 30 --staged | tee deployment.log
  ```

You will need to provide AWS Access key & Secret via environment variables.

Hope this helps or gives you a way to solve this problem.

**Note -** You can even configure `.ebextensions` & `.elasticbeanstalk` directory in your CD configuration so that it doesn't get checked into GIT.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I assumed it was a bad idea because `eb init` seems to add the dirs to .gitignore.